# Call variables from one javascript file to another

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I call the variables that I stored in one javascript file from another?

var.js

```
var VAR = new Object;
VAR.myvalue = "Yeah!";
```

then I want to use VAR.myvalue here

sample.js

```
alert(VAR.myvalue);
```

Comment: Did you include var.js before sample.js? And maybe put the `alert` somewhere it's sure to get called?

Comment: Yes, I did. It seems there's problem with new Object on widget, because I've tried this sample on a simple html and it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, instead of

```
var VAR = new Object;
VAR.myvalue = "Yeah!";
```

Opt for

```
var VAR = {
    myvalue: "Yeah!"
 };
```

But so long as `var.js` is referenced **first**, **before** sample.js, what you have should work fine.

var.js will declare, and initialize VAR, which will be read from the script declared in sample.js

Comment: I created a sample just for now, yeah it works thanks. But in my case because I'm applying this on a widget and it didn't. Maybe there's problem with my code. :) but, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Include both JavaScript file in one HTML file, place `sample.js` after `var.js` so that `VAR.myvalue` is valid:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="var.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try separating your scope using a [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth). This will eliminate headaches in the future.

**var.js**

```
var someVar = (function () {
  var total = 10; // Local scope, protected from global namespace

  return {
    add: function(num){
      total += num;
    }
  , sub: function(num){
      total -= num;
    }
  , total: function(){
      return total;
    }
  };
}());
```

Then you can use that object's methods and properties from anywhere else.

**sample.js**

```
someVar.add(5);
someVar.sub(6);
alert(someVar.total());
```

Comment: Hey, this is one works on my widget. Can you make this more simple because I just want to store my values to other javascript and just call it. Just what I've stated above. Thanks for advance :)

Comment: LOL, the point was to 'learn you something' about Javascript OOP. Adam Rackis answer above is the same without the methods, only object properties but essentially works the same way.

Comment: @Pastor Bones - you didn't actually answer the question: the key point that you didn't mention is that "var.js" must be included _before_ "sample.js". (Also, I agree that the module pattern can be useful, but only if you actually need methods. If you just need a few data properties a simple object literal is the way to go.)

Comment: @Pastor, yeah but what I've stated above it didn't work on my widget. I just want to ask if there's better method in doing that, that will save more space. Because there's a lot of values I want to store.

Comment: the return statement can return functions or properties and both are accessed in the same way.

Comment: I know that, but anything more than an object literal is overkill if you know you don't need functions.